# Why is the private Modifier makes the program to execute private method in super class although called through sub class object?

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java program to implement the overridding the `grow` method.

The overridding works perfectly if method `grow` in class `Tree` (parent class) is declared with default access modifier and prints `"Oak is growing"`. 
But when its changed to `private`, the method from the parent class (`Tree`) executes.

```java
// Code with  grow() default modifier
public abstract class TreeGrow {
    void grow() {
        System.out.println("Tree is growing");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TreeGrow tree = new Oak();
        tree.grow();
    }
}

class Oak extends TreeGrow {
    protected void grow() {
        System.out.println("Oak is Growing");
    } 
}
```

```java
// Code with private grow
public abstract class TreeGrow {
    private void grow() {
        System.out.println("Tree is growing");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TreeGrow tree = new Oak();
        tree.grow();
    }
}

class Oak extends TreeGrow {
    protected void grow() {
        System.out.println("Oak is Growing");
    } 
}
```

Why is the private method in `Tree` class executed, when the method is called through  Oak object?

Comment: Don't see any difference between the two code blocks.

Comment: When you override a method include @Override annotation and your compiler will tell you if you've successfully overriden a method or not.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen their edit needs an approval. Maybe you or somebody upvoting your comment could approve the edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your object is of type `TreeGrow`. Your main method therefore calls the method `TreeGrow.grow()`. The private method is not overridden and therefore the "most-suitable" method is called, which is the `private void grow()` one.

You need to cast your object to the corresponding type to use its method. Try using `((Oak)tree).grow` (or alternatively `Oak tree = new Oak();`). This should execute your method.

**Edit:**
Sorry for the "vague" explanation. I was in a hurry and wanted to help as fast as possible. After re-visiting this, it really is not well-written. As the linked "duplicate" question (and the respective answers) describe everything in a more elaborate manner, I would recommend reading there.

Comment: This is a strange situation. I downvoted you at first and now I cannot remove it. Can you improve your explanation a little bit? Your answer seems to imply that casting is changing the object, but the two main points are. TreeGrow.grow is a different method than Oak.grow, and casting causes the compiler to choose the Oak method. Essentially they've shadowed TreeGrow.grow but not overriden.